# Как применить Nullable-контекст ко всему проекту в unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, null

В unity пока что доступен только c#9 и там ещё нету по дефолту включенного nullable-контекста( как в с#10). Я знаю что можно в начале каждого скрипта писать:

> #nullable enable

Но могу ли я наподобие global using написать в отдельном скрипте как-то этот enable, что бы не писать его в каждом скрипте?

Comment: В `.csproj` это [задается](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/language#nullable), не знаю как там у вас в Unity, но скорей всего тоже должен быть.

Comment: [аналогичный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64229527/customizing-csproj-in-unity-enable-nullable-reference-types)